# apple music app create playlist by third part apps

Tags: playlist, ios9.3, apple-music

I wants to create a playlist named `"My App Playlist"` on `apple music` from my application. So that user can able to save tracks played from my application. How can i meet my requirement .

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05122016a